# How can I fix ObserveAsState not working consistently in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

Sometimes my observe as state work sometimes dont, basically it worked i instantly commited my code, and 2 days before it didnt work. I have a project, and im trying to implement compose in it, basically a composable inside a fragment. I think that it may be related to livedata, in other screen that uses the same livedata it works but in my composable the livedata dont seem to update.
My compose version is 1.1.1

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$legacySupportVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion"

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$androidMaterialVersion"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$cardViewVersion"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerViewVersion"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintLayoutVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gsonVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android:flexbox:$flexBoxVersion"

    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$androidMultidexVersion"

    // room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"

    // lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycleCompileVersion"

    // Socket
    implementation("io.socket:socket.io-client:$socketIoClientVersion") {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07"

    //implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:1.0.0-alpha07"

    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.1.0-beta04"

    //Lottie
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    // Shimmer Placeholder Facebook
    implementation "com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:$facebookShimmerVersion"

    // Timber
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timberVersion"

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:$androidAnnotationVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:$mockkVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidTestEspressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$androidTestEspressoVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'

    // test
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:$mockkVersion"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.1.0'
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3"
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutinesVersion"

    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.7"
}
```

```
class ListaDeAmigosComposeFragment : Fragment() {

    //lateinit var viewModel: ContactViewModel

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = ListaDeAmigosComposeFragment()
    }

    private var fragmentListener = WeakReference<FragmentListener>(null)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        containter: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) : View {
        return ComposeView(
            requireContext()
        ).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(
                ViewCompositionStrategy
                    .DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed
            )

            setContent {
                MessengerTheme {
//                    val factory = ContactViewModelFactory()
//                    fragmentListener = WeakReference(context as FragmentListener)
//
//                    viewModel =
//                        ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[ContactViewModel::class.java]

                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize(),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        FriendsListHeader()
                        FriendsList()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FriendsList(
   // viewModel: ContactViewModel,
) {
    val factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory{
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return ContactViewModel(
                contactRepository = ContactServiceLocator.contactRepository,
                contactMapper = ContactMapper(gson = WithoutDependenciesServiceLocator.gson)
            ) as T
        }
    }

    val contactViewModel: ContactViewModel = viewModel(factory = factory)

    val friendsList: List<Contact> by contactViewModel.listContact.observeAsState(initial = listOf())

    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    //val friendsList = contactViewModel.listContact.observeAsState(initial = listOf()).value
    val listWithoutManager = friendsList.filter {
        it.contactId != ConstantsUtils.ConstManager.contactIdManager &&
                it.contactId != ConstantsUtils.ConstManagerAGF.contactIdManager &&
                it.contactId != ConstantsUtils.ConstManagerSD.contactIdManager &&
                it.contactId != ConstantsUtils.ConstInvestments.contactId
    }


    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
    ) {
        items(items = listWithoutManager){ friend ->
            ContactSelectedViewObserver(contactViewModel)
            friendCard(friend, contactViewModel)
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun FriendsListHeader() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Orange)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
    ){
        Text(
            modifier= Modifier
                .padding(0.dp, 6.dp),
            text = "Bem vindo",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 24.sp
        )

        Text(text = "Sobre o que você quer falar?", color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp)
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MessengerTheme {
        FriendsListHeader()
    }
}
```